# Run several commands until an exception DOESN'T occur? (Python)

Tags: python, exception

Typically a try/except block can be used to run a bunch of statements until one of them causes an exception.

I want to do the opposite - run a set of statements where EACH of them will likely cause an exception, but one of them will not.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
try:
    c = 1 / 0       # this will cause an exception
    c = 1 / (1 - 1) # this will cause an exception
    c = int("i am not an integer") 
                    # this will cause an exception
    c = 1           # this will not cause an exception
    c = 2           # this statement should not be reached
    c = None        # this would be a final fallback in case everything exceptioned

print c         # with this code, c should print "1"
```

The way I want to use something like this is with data parsing. The user may provide some data which could be in one of several different formats. Attempting to parse the various formats will produce exceptions if the data doesn't match the format. There could be tens of different possible formats. The statements would be listed in order of preference. As soon as one of the parsers succeeds, that's the result I want in the variable.

Wrapping each try inside try/excepts would result in some ugly spaghetti code.

```
c = None

try:
    c = 1 / 0
except:
    pass

if (c == None):
    try:
        c = 1 / (1 - 1)
    except:
        pass

if (c == None):
    try:
        c = int("i am not an int")
    except:
        pass

... and so on
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see where is your spaghetti code, you have at most two level of indentation.

Comment: Maybe that's the wrong term, but either way, all those if/try/except blocks are much harder to read than if you could just have a list of statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply making it a function? I'm using your pseudo code, so no better functionality, just more readable;

```
def doIt():

    try:
        return 1 / 0
    except:
        pass

    try:
        return 1 / (1 - 1)
    except:
        pass

    try:
        return int("i am not an int")
    except:
        pass

c = doIt()
```

Comment: This worked great as half the solution I was hoping for. The only downside was having to replicate the try/except block, but this combined with the next solution turned out to be the best way to do this! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, use lambda functions in an array:

```
L = [ lambda : 1 / 0, 
      lambda : 1 / (1 - 1), 
      lambda : int("i am not an int"), 
      lambda : 2 ]

for l in L:
  try:
    x = l()
    break
  except:
    pass
print x
```

In your current example/request you don't need/use input data to your tests, but eventually you will later on, that's super easy with lambdas.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson why the peer did not accept the edit but made by himself exactly the same as suggested before?

Comment: Ah, yes I can see, I a break had slipped my copy-paste, think Joachim have fixed it for me already

Comment: @SaulloCastro Sorry, never saw your suggested edit, I was not the one rejecting it. I just added the break since it was a semi obvious typo in an otherwise working solution.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson OK that is all right... I don't know how does this peer reviewing thing works here, but anyway, it is quite useful

Comment: Still, isn't it smarter to stuff all the tests int an array and iterate over it instead of typing try-except over and over again? Or is it considered less pythonic because of reduced readability?

Comment: @mogul Keeping in mind that more complex lambdas can be broken out and added as functions to your array, I can see your solution being _much_ better when the number of expressions is high, while if there are - like in this case - just a few expressions, I'd rather write them out. But then I never claimed to write "Pythonic" code, just as readable as possible :)

Comment: This is the best solution to me. I actually took both from this answer and the previous one. I wrapped my parse code inside a function, then used this method to produce a list of lambdas to iterate over, having a "return" inside the try block. This means I do not have to duplicate any code anywhere, which is really ideal. Thanks!